# Seeing mode of file without listing all files

Tags: ls

I want to see the mode of file/folder `foo`, in the form `drwxrwxrwx`. I would normally do `ls -lah | grep foo`, but in this case the folder had so many subfolders, that it took a long time for `ls` to run. Is there an alternative way that would run quickly? Also I'm a bit annoyed by the use of `grep`, because maybe my file is called `May` and then every file that has a creation date in the month of May would show up? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Why not just `ls -lh foo`?

Comment: You can add the `-d` flag to prevent it from descending into subdirectories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As steeldriver commented, the easiest way is to use `ls`'s `-d` [flag](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

> -d, --directory list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

Answer (score 3):

just use the stat tool:

```
stat filename
```

with this you can see all options, so with -f you could specify an own format:

```
man stat
```

Answer (score 0):

Call ls -l on the file/directory itself.

```
ls -lhd foo
```

If it's got a name you're not 100% sure of, use expandable terms:

```
ls -lhd foo*
```